# php mail() not sending styles

Tags: php, css, email, styles

I am trying to send style information along with an email via PHP mail() function. Unfortunately, even though my mail client is set to accept styled emails it still just renders as plain html text.

```
$to = $email;
    $subject = "Subject Details";
    $message='<html><body><table width="600" height="840" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">';
    $message.='<tr><td height="110"><img src="https://user.co.uk/images/logo.jpg" alt="SignDox" width="300" height="100" /></td></tr>';
    $message.='<tr><td height="29" bgcolor="#5C1561">&nbsp;</td></tr>';
    $message.='<tr><td height="537" valign="top">';
    $message.="Message Goes Here\n\n";
    $message.="Username: ".$new_agent_id."\n";
    $message.="Password: ".$pass1."\n\n";
    $message.="To sign in to your user panel follow this link: \n";
    $message.="Inside your admin section you will be able to change your username and password.\n";
    $message.='</td></tr>';
    $message.='<tr><td height="140" bgcolor="#5C1561">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></body></html>';
    $from = "no-reply@sender.co.uk";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the correct headers in order to send HTML formatted emails. This can be done very simply using:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

However, I would urge you to use the `PHPMailer` Class. This class will handle all headers and anything else you may need. You can easily add attachments, embed images, send via SMTP etc...

It is a fantastic class, and not to mention the amount you will learn with objects and classes, expecially if you are a newbie to PHP :-)

See here for the [PHPMailer Class](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 4):

To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

**Note:**

1) If intending to send HTML or otherwise Complex mails, it is recommended to use the PEAR package » PEAR::Mail_Mime.

2) It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient.

Please read more this: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Most people forget mime version

Answer (score 1):

Set the content type, and charset as desired. You should also terminate your from header with `\r\n`.

```
$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
<?php
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From:" . $from;
/*
$headers[] = "Bcc: JJ Chong <bcc@domain2.com>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";  */ optional

mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function send_mail($from,$fromName,$to,$object,$bodyText,$bodyHtml){
    $site = "mywebsite.ca";
    $from = $fromName." <".$from.">";
    $limite = "_----------=_parties_".md5(uniqid (rand()));

    $header  = "Reply-to: ".$from."\n";
    $header .= "From: ".$from."\n";
    $header .= "X-Sender: <".$site.">\n";
    $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n";
    $header .= "X-auth-smtp-user: ".$from." \n";    
    $header .= "X-abuse-contact: ".$from." \n"; 
    $header .= "Date: ".date("D, j M Y G:i:s O")."\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"".$limite."\"";

    $message = "";
    $message .= "--".$limite."\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain\n";
    $message .= "charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $message .= $bodyText;

    $message .= "\n\n--".$limite."\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; ";
    $message .= "charset=\"iso-8859-1\"; ";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit;\n\n";
    $message .= $bodyHtml;

    $message .= "\n--".$limite."--";
    if(mail($to,$object,$message,$header)){
      //echo all
    }
    else{
      //echo mssage not submit
    }
}
```

hope this function can help you. try to use this function to as your send_mail, then at the buttom try to
write a condition to see if your message is submitted.You just needed to give inputs in it

Answer (score 0):

```
//your header should be like this
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```